# XPath получить значение родительского тега

Tags: xpath, php

Добрый день, дорогое сообщество.
Не так давно начал изучать XPath. Столкнулся с необходимостью получить текст родительского тега.
Вот ситуация, xml следующего содержания:

```
<qtopic><name>Тема 1 основные понятия</name>
          <questions> 
              <question>
                  <category>single</category>
                  <qtype>Выбор одного ответа</qtype>
                  <weight>1</weight>
                  <title>Выберите правильный ответ:</title>
                  <questionbody> 2 Абярыце правільны адказ:</questionbody>
                  <answers>
                    <answer type="true" ><name>Правильно1</name></answer>
                    <answer type="false"><name>Не Правильно4</name></answer>
                    <answer type="false"><name>Не Правильно3</name></answer>
                    <answer type="false"><name>Не Правильно1</name></answer>
                    <answer type="false"><name>Не Правильно2</name></answer>
                  </answers>
              </question>
              <question>
                  <category>single</category>
                  <qtype>Выбор одного ответа</qtype>
                  <weight>1</weight>
                  <title>Выберите правильный ответ:</title>
                  <questionbody> 2 Абярыце правільны адказ:</questionbody>
                  <answers>
                    <answer type="true" ><name>Правильно1</name></answer>
                    <answer type="false"><name>Не Правильно4</name></answer>
                    <answer type="false"><name>Не Правильно3</name></answer>
                    <answer type="false"><name>Не Правильно1</name></answer>
                    <answer type="false"><name>Не Правильно2</name></answer>
                  </answers>
              </question>
        </questions>
      </qtopic>
```

В php
Получаю значение вопроса так:

```
$var = $_GET['qstn-number'];//номер вопроса
$comparisonAnswers  = $xml->xpath("qtopic/questions/question[".$var."]/answers/answer/name");
```

Вопрос, как получить значение тега name в теге qtopic?

```
<qtopic><name>**Тема 1 основные понятия**</name>
```

зная только номер вопроса...т.е. узнать тему по вопросу

Спасибо, буду благодарен любой информации.
Сейчас пытаюсь найти истину в при помощи функции  **getParent()** , но пока без успеха.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А какая у вас структура документа? Если у вас в одном файле хранится одна тема, тогда зачем так всё усложнять?

Вы просто смотрите `$xml->name` и всё.

**UPD.**

Если у вас сквозная нумерация вопросов по всем темам в документе, то можно использовать следующие запросы:

`$comparisonAnswers  = $xml->xpath("(//question)[".$var."]/answers/answer/name");` - для получения всех вариантов ответа по вопросу

`$qtopicname2 = $xml->xpath("(//question)[".$var."]/../../name");` - для получения наименования темы по данному вопросу

Comment: Как раз  проблема в том, что это лишь кусок из всего xml -файла. Таких тем может много.

Comment: А "номер вопроса" по какому принципу считается? В рамках темы или в рамках всего документа?

Comment: В рамках всего документа.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все прекрасно работает.